# Gitignore everything except src directory

Tags: ros, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a catkin workspace with the following structure:

```
catkin_ws/
├── build
├── devel
└── src
```

As expected all my code/packages are in the **src** directory but the base directory, catkin_ws, is being tracked by GIT.

My problem is that each time I have to execute **catkin_make**, git status reports back  modifications to **build** and **devel** directories - which I want ignored.

I created a **.gitignore** file under **catkin_ws** with the following content:

```
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar

build/
devel/*
```

But, I still get the same modified files in build and devel as shown below:

```
> On branch master Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   build/CMakeCache.txt
        modified:   build/CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake
        modified:   build/CMakeFiles/Makefile2
        modified:   build/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt
        modified:   build/CTestTestfile.cmake
        modified:   build/Makefile
        modified:   build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py
        modified:   build/catkin_generated/installspace/_setup_util.py
        modified:   build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake
        modified:   build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py
        modified:   build/catkin_generated/setup_cached.sh
        modified:   build/catkin_generated/stamps/Project/_setup_util.py.stamp
        modified:   build/catkin_make.cache
        modified:   build/cmake_install.cmake
        modified:   devel/_setup_util.py

Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        src/beginner_tutorial/
        src/my-robot/
        src/oreilly/
```

Can anyone help, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277674/gitignore-everything-except-src-directory/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2017-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-09**:
If you have a collection of related packages you can create a [metapackage](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackage) that houses those related packages and put that under version control instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The proper way to approach this would be to not version your entire Catkin workspace, but just the packages / directories *inside* the [source space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Source_Space).

See #q264600, #q216664 and #q257855 for some older questions and answers about this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2017-12-09**:
I think you are right.